# How can I split a string and add them to vector?

Tags: r, string, strsplit

I'd like to split a character vector so that additional members are added to the length of the vector.

```
> va <- c("a", "b", "c;d;e")
[1] "a"     "b"     "c;d;e"
> vb <- strsplit(va, ";")
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "d" "e"
```

Can can I get `vb` vector in the same format as `va` vector so that I get 1-dimensional, 5 member vector in `vb` as such?

```
[1] "a"     "b"     "c"      "d"       "e"
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
unlist(vb)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Comment: perfect! did not know about this function

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
scan(text=va, sep=";",what="")
#Read 5 items
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```